# Removing object from SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, android-sharedpreferences

I'm trying to remove a specific object from sharedPreferences, I've tried a few times, but I don't know how to do it properly.

These are the two methods I use to save and exclude Disciplines from SharedPreferences:

```
public void saveDisciplineData(Discipline discipline){
    editor.putString("Discipline" + count, gson.toJson(discipline));
    editor.commit();
    count++;
}

public void excludeDisciplineData(Discipline discipline){
    for (int i = 0; i < count ; i++) {
        Discipline d = gson.fromJson(sp.getString("discipline" + i, ""), new TypeToken<Discipline>() {
        }.getType());
        if (d.equals(discipline)){
            editor.remove("discipline" + i);
            break;
        }
    }

    editor.commit();
    count--;
}
```

How can I delete a specific Discipline Object?

Comment: Why not save and load a `List<Discipline>`? Or, why not use some other data store, such as JSON files or a SQLite database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using Discipline with capital D when saving the value and discipline in lower cases when trying to remove. 
It would be good if you create a constant DISCIPLINE = "discipline" to avoid this kind of problems.